# How to use SonarLint in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

I was assigned to use SonarQube for code quality. But while I'm downloading it's plugin to Eclipse I understood it is deprecated and new one is SonarLint.

But as so far I couldn't find any good documentation to how to use SonarLint. How to check java project using that. I only got touch with Youtube videos. But sadly they are really really unclear to me.

If can direct me to a good place to gain clear knowledge on this I'll be really grateful to you.

Comment: This pops up in the Close Votes Review. I think one should clarify if this is Offtopic or not. I'm afraid it is... :/

Comment: @hellow why would this be off topic?

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* 3 votes so far for this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can install SonarLint from the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint) and read the [official SonarLint documentation](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/)

Comment: I installed the plugin. Problem is how to use it.

Comment: @pippilongstocking The first things is to enable it for a project: you right click over a project (in the project view), Configure -> Enable SonarLint. Then, files should be automatically analyse when opening them or saving them. You can also analyze all the project with right click over it -> SonarLint -> Analyze all files. Issues are marked in the editor and also appear in the "SonarLint Issues" view (Window -> Show View -> SonarLint Issues).

Comment: @Duarte-SonarSourceTeam : is there any way (eg through maven's pom.xml) to make the "enable SonarLint for the project" step automatic? I mean: if I import an existing Maven project into Eclipse, with SonarLint plugin already installed, what could I do to have the SonarLint plugin activated for that project automatically?

Comment: @duarte-sonarsource-team : I cannot see any option to analyze all files in SonarLint 2.1.0 plugin. Was that purposefully removed? If yes, then how are we supposed to analyse entire project?

Comment: Analyzing a full project is not a task for SonarLint. This is was SonarQube is made for.

Comment: Hmmm. So basically I have to go to SonarQube to see what files have issues and then individually search those files in Eclipse? I don't want to *only* avoid adding new issues, I'd like to also easily find and remove old ones...

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam how do you configure rules if you aren't using sonarqube then?

Comment: We have now changed our mind, and recent versions of SonarLint for Eclipse and IntelliJ offer a way to run a full analysis.

Comment: @MikeD This is currently not possible to tune rules with SonarLint only. This is still an open subject.

Comment: I have installed  sonarlint from eclipse marketplace , but I couldn't find any option to configure it.. I am using Eclipse Juno.. any help will be appreciated for how sonarlint works in eclipse.

Comment: while installing I get an error  ```Unable to read repository at https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to analyze a complete project with the Sonar Lint plugin, you can trick the plugin by searching all Java files with a text editor and replacing "package" with " package". This will cause SVN or git changes. Open the "Sonar Lint Report" view and run the analysis on the "Current project". Afterwards, revert all your SVN changes. Do *not* run the analysis again as the Sonar Lint Plugin only analyzes changed files.

I found this helpful when I had no project on the Sonar server available.

Answer (score 1):

You can install SonarLint as described by Sumit Singh.
Then you can link your project to a sonarqube server as described [here](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/)

After that just make a change and save it. Sonarlint will automatically analyze the project for you. Cause analyzing is enabled by default (as far as i know)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late but try looking at this doc/wiki about SonarLint for Eclipse:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-eclipse/wiki